# Opencart - Blank page when clicking 'order'

Tags: php, opencart

When i click the order button from admin i am getting a blank page.

I have tried error reporting and it does not print anything.
I have also checked the error log and again nothing is recorded.

Its generally any page to do with orders that is blank. Could it be something in the header of  the main order file? Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php
check your phpinfo() to information, usually there is file "error_log" in the same directory the script fails to execute..

Comment: Unfortunately I've already checked that error log as it already has a section in the opencart admin to display this log which showed nothing. In the end i paid someone to complete it for me. Unfortunately i don't know much about what they did. But it was something to do with its exit statements. Thanks for trying!

Comment: other opensource commerce solutions exist such as Zencart , don't know what made you stick to opencart so much, but its ok